# Nested Promises in WinJS and How to Wait for Final Completion

Tags: javascript, background, nested, winjs, promise

I am new to promises and WinJS, and am currently working on an app.

At some point I need to download a file using backgroundDownloader and save it in local folder, then read it and process the data.

There is a function that initiates this process, and I want to wait for the completion of the whole process before proceeding. However through some debugging I realized that after the first promise has returned successfully, the program proceeds whereas it's not supposed to (I think). I believe its supposed to wait for all the promises to return successfully one after another.

Here is the code:

the function that initiates the process:

function startDownload() {
      getData.done( function () {
            blah blah blah
      }
}

the getData function which is called by the function above:

```
    getData: function () {
        return downloadFtp(staticUrl, filePath)
            .then(function (response) {
                var data = openFile(response.resultFile.name);
                return data;
            });
    }
```

the downloadFtp function which downloads and saves the content and returns a promise

```
    downloadFtp: function (uriString, fileName) {
        var download = null;
        try {
            // Asynchronously create the file in the pictures folder.
            return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
                .then(function (newFile) {
                    var uri = Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriString);
                    var downloader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader();

                    // Create a new download operation.
                    download = downloader.createDownload(uri, newFile);

                    // Start the download and persist the promise to be able to cancel the download.
                    return download.startAsync();
                });
        } catch (err) {
            displayException();
        }
    },
```

the openFile function that opens the local file and returns a promise:

```
    openFile: function (file) {
        return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync(file)
           .then(function (content) {
               var content = readFile(content);
               return content;
           });
    },
```

the readFile function that reads the data in the file and sends it to the data processor:

```
    readFile: function (content) {
        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(content)
            .done(function (timestamp) {
                var text = processData(timestamp);
                return text;
            });
    },
```

in the startDownload function, I have noticed that it doesnt wait for the completion of the whole process before going inside the done() function. Is there an easy fix for this, or easy way to work with nested promises in general?

I would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to turn your sample to pseudocode to make it easier to spot the problem.

```
downloadFtp.then(getFileAsync.then(readTextAsync.done(processData)))
           .done(BLAH)
```

The problem is that downloadFile being resolved triggers two callbacks, getFileAsync and BLAH. The getFileAsync callback returns a promise which is probably unresolved at this state, but the callback still ends instantly, so BLAH is free to run. At a later point getFileAsync is resolved and the other callbacks are called.

The best thing you can do is switch to a chaining model for promises, making it easier to control the execution flow.

Comment: While I was waiting for answer, I changed the done keyword in "done(processData)" to "then", and everything seems to work again. I can't quite see how that could fix it.
Your reply also makes sense. thanks. I'll try to change the code to reflect your suggestion.